# Array.prototype.splice with negative indexes and delete count greater than 1 not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

Let's say we have an array like `var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and we need to remove the last two items. While there could be many ways of doing this, I tried using this approach:

`x.splice(-1, 2)`

ideally, as I understand this should remove last two elements. But it doesn't instead it removes only one value.

Can anyone please explain what went wrong?

Comment: Why `-1`? `x.splice(-2)` would work. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice.

Comment: yes agree that works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to remove last 2 items you should use `x.splice(-2)`
First parameter is start point and second (not necessary - default is to the end of array) is the number of elements to remove.
You should read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
x.splice(-2,2);
```

First argument is "minus index" (index which start from array end) and second means number of elements to remove

```js
var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

x.splice(-2,2);

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it takes the number of elements to delete (2 here), to the **RIGHT** of the starting index mentioned (here -1), and **NOT** to the left of the index (as we are thinking logically).

so x.splice(-1,2) tries to delete 2 elements starting from -1 to the RIGHT of -1. But only 1 element is there. so it deletes only 1 element.

For the same reason:
x.splice(-3,2);  // deletes 4,5. Not 3,4 (going to the left).